# Cant log in with right info, page just refreshes

Tags: php

Heres the issue, I am trying to login with the correct info (triple checked through phpmyadmin) but all it is doing is redirecting back to the login page like the info is not right.

Login Form (at the top of page)

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      include "includes/class.users.php";
      if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $users->login($email, $password);
      }
    ?>
```

Login Form

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="login">
    <div id="wrappermiddle">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <div id="username_input"> 
    <div id="username_inputleft"></div>
        <div id="username_inputmiddle">
        <input name="email" type="text" id="myusername" placeholder="Email Address">
        <img id="url_user" src="./images/mailicon.png" alt="">      
        </div><!--ends username_inputmiddle-->
        <div id="username_inputright"></div>                   
    </div><!--ends username_input-->

   <div id="password_input">
    <div id="password_inputleft"></div>
        <div id="password_inputmiddle">       
        <input name="password" type="password" id="mypassword" placeholder="Password">
        <img id="url_password" src="./images/passicon.png" alt="">        
        </div><!--ends password_inputmiddle-->
     <div id="password_inputright"></div>
    </div><!--ends password_input-->

<div id="submit"> 
<input type="image" src="./images/submit.png" name="login" value="Login">      
</form>
```

class.users.php

```
<?php
  include "class.database.php";
  class Users extends Database {
    public function login($email, $password) {
      $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
      $stmt->store_result();
      if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
          session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
          header("Location: dashboard.php");
        }
      } else {
          return false;
      }
      $stmt->close();
      $stmt->free_result();
    }
  }
  $users = new users();
?>
```

dashbord.php at the top

```
 <?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    } else {
header ("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

EDIT - I tried loggin in with a bad password and I get the error - There is an error

When I login with the correct info, if just refreshes the login page.

Comment: You're saving passwords as plain text?

Comment: Not sure, I found a tutorial trying to switch my site to mysqli

Comment: You have session_start(); twice, once on your login form and then again in your login method.

Comment: What debugging have you attempted?

Comment: I took it off the login page but it is still doing the same. As for debugging, I have looked at the console and nothing strange is coming up.

Comment: Added echo $mysqli->error;  and got this - Warning: mysqli_stmt::free_result(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in

Comment: Does dashboard.php redirect to login.php? That would explain the page "refreshing"

Comment: What tutorial are you using? The plain text passwords means it's well worth avoiding. Still, at least the user input is parameterised in the query!

Comment: I would have to find it again. I dont know what is going on. Any good (better) tutorials on how to create a mysqli admin system? I have looked and cant find anything worth while.

Comment: This is the [Tutorial](https://www.2freehosting.com/forum/topic455-guide-php-mysqli-oop-simple-login-script.html) I followed

Comment: I have asked on several boards and no one can figure out why it isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're setting the header after some html has been rendered.

My approach would be to include in the Login page

`if ($_SESSION['loggedin] = true) {
 header("Location: dashboard.php");
} else {
 login page
}`